# Разложение функции котангенса в ряд

Tags: c

[image: Разложение функции в ряд]

Язык C (Си). Результат совсем не тот, какой хотелось бы. Реализовал без рекуррентных формул и что-то сделал не так. Числа Бернулли вроде как верны.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

long int Factorial(long int x) {        //функция вычисления факториала
    if (x == 0 || x == 1)
        return 1;   //по определению факториал нуля и единицы равен единице
    else
        return x*Factorial(x-1);    //функция вызывается внутри себя (рекурсия)
}

float Bink (long int n, long int k) {       //Биномиальный коэффициент Ньютона
    return 1.0*Factorial(n)/Factorial(k)/Factorial(n-k);
}

float Bernoulli(long int n) {       //Число Бернулли
    if (n<=0) return 1;
    else  {
        float s = 0;
        long k;
        for(k = 1;k<=n;k++)
            s+=Bink(n+1,k+1)*Bernoulli(n-k);
        return -1.0/(n+1)*s;
    }
}

float Cotangent(int x) {
    int i = 1;
    float p = 1.0, s = 1.0,
    eps = 0.00001;

    for (;fabs(p)>eps;i++) {
        p = (pow(2,2*i)*Bernoulli(i)*pow(x,2*i-1))/Factorial(2*i);
        s+=p;
        #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("\ni = %i, p = %f, s = %f",i,p,s);   //отладочные сообщения
        #endif
    }
    return 1/(float)x - s;
}

int main() {
    printf("\tЧИСЛА БЕРНУЛЛИ:\n");
    for (i = 0; i<=10; i++)
        printf("B[%d] = %f\n", i, Bernoulli(i));

    printf("\n\n\tРАЗЛОЖЕНИЕ ФУНКЦИИ\n\n");
    printf("\n\n%f", Cotangent(1));

    return 0;
}
```

Прикрепляю результаты отладки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, результат (0.888889) совсем не совпадает с реальным значением функции (cot(1) = 0.642092). В чем же дело?

Answer (score 1):

Я что-то не припомню такой формулы. Ошибка, видимо в ней самой.

Гляньте, пожалуйста, на [эту формулу](http://1cov-edu.ru/mat_analiz/funktsii/tangens/math_941.5_3b76941ac574992afaf7ca50118cb32a.png). Взял [отсюда](http://1cov-edu.ru/mat_analiz/funktsii/tangens/). Вот я её подставил вместо Вашей - и ответ сошёлся. Если Вы настаиваете на том, что Ваша формула верна, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на источник, проверим.

Comment: Мда, действительно совпадает. 
Формула из методички университета, думаю, надо обратиться к преподавателю. Там и числа Бернулли в качестве примера совсем не верны.

Comment: Ну, методички вузов очень часто пестрят ошибками, сам был преподавателем, знаю, как и зачем они пишутся. Возможно, конечно, в методичке вашей иная запись того же самого, так как само разложение справа от последнего знака равенства верное. В таком случае нужно детально изучать программу по шагам, сверяя на каждом шаге каждую операцию с ручным счётом.